# Replace keyword in a heading with php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to replace keywords such as "the", "and" etc.. in headings and replace it with a span in the heading tags.

Ex:

```
<h2>This is the heading</h2>
```

to become

```
<h2>This is <span>the</span> heading</h2>
```

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE**

I found something that works for what I had wanted:

```
$(function() {
$('h2').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(/the/, "<span>the</span>");
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PHP only solution (without regex):

```
$string = "<h2>This is the heading</h2>";
$toReplace = array("the", "and");

$replaceTo = array_map(function ($val) { return "<span>$val</span>"; }, $toReplace);
$newString = str_replace($toReplace, $replaceTo, $string);

print $newString; // prints as expected: <h2>This is <span>the</span> heading</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need it to be able to select any <h2>. Not necessarily a specific <h2>.

Comment: @Chrisp you want only in headings? go search a dom parser.

Comment: @Chrisp As this answer seems to have solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: I tried but it says I need 15 reputation. Also I found something that works for what I had wanted:

  $(function() {
    $('h2').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).html(function(i, html) {
            return html.replace(/the/, "<span class='the'>the</span>");
        });
    });
});

Comment: @Chrisp don't click on the arrows, click on the green bordered tick.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you do it and extend your words dynamically:

```
$special_words = array("the", "and", "or") ;
$words = implode("|", $special_words) ;

$string = "<h2>This is the heading</h2>" ;
$new = preg_replace("/({$words})/i", "<span>$1</span>", $string) ;

echo $new ;
```

Answer (score 1):

very easy with regexp, this example only use one keyword, for multiple keywords use an array.

```
$string = "<h2>This is the heading</h2>";
$string = preg_replace("/(the|end)/", "<span>$1</span>", $string);
```